# How to force ssh to use an identity by key digest (not by file)

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to checkout something via `git` in a remote machine. `git` calls `ssh -vvv`, and in the debug output I can see:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:YaH**************************************** agent
debug1: Will attempt key:  ED25519 SHA256:cPD9**************************** agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_xmss
```

And further down

```
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:YaH**************************************** agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:YaH****************************************
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:YaH****************************************
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

But then the clone fails, because this is in fact the wrong key; the correct key to use is the second one (beginning `cPD9`).

How can I force ssh to give preference to the second key?

Ordinarily, I would do `ssh -i ./path/to/key/id_rsa`, but in this case, the key is added to the keychain by CircleCI. i.e. **there is no file with this key in the VM**. This is evident in the log file, where the second line does not have a path to a file. The only thing I know is the digest of the key, and I would like to force SSH to use this. I've looked through the man pages but I can't see anything obvious.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/273094/432690 ?

Comment: Yes, I think that works. The key thing is that `ssh-add -L` will reproduce the contents of the *.pub file, which you can then pass to `ssh -i`.

Comment: My workaround for this was to remove the existing key using `ssh-add -d /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa`, but note this may break things further down your pipeline that depend on that key. I think the correct alternative would be to use the approach in the above comments.